# Selenium (Java) - Arbitrary instanciation of FirefoxDriver using profile

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using the Selenium FirefoxDriver and whatever I do, I want it to start with **my** default user profile (addons, etc). I got that part working. I also wrote a simple GUI that helps me controlling my programme. This GUI has a button which starts the driver and another one which calls **quit()**.

The problem:

1. I click start -> Works fine. The FirefoxDriver gets loaded with all addons, bookmarks, ...
2. I click close -> Works fine. The browser closes cleanly (as far as i can tell).
3. **I click start again -> The browser starts, but with a blank profile. No addons, nothing**

This is how I instanciate the driver. I have no idea what might cause the issue. Please help!

```
public static final FirefoxProfile FIREFOX_PROFILE = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
public static final FirefoxBinary FIREFOX_BIN = new FirefoxBinary(new File("..."));

public static FirefoxDriver getNewFirefoxInstance() {
    FirefoxDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver(FIREFOX_BIN, FIREFOX_PROFILE);
    firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return firefox;
}

private FirefoxDriver firefox = null;

JButton newFirefox = new JButton("Start FF");
newFirefox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (firefox == null){
            firefox = getNewFirefoxInstance();
        }
    }
});

JButton closeFirefox = new JButton("Close FF");
closeFirefox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (firefox != null){
            firefox.quit();
            firefox = null;
        }
    }
});
```